# Spring Data JPA Multi-FK Join

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

The problem I have is with the querying of data from a chain of 3 tables via the JPA entity framework in a Spring Boot v1.5.3 application. The models are defined as follows:

```
ValidationField {  
  @Id id,  
  name,  

@OneToMany(
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "validationMessage")  
  Set<ValidationFieldMessage> messages
}


ValidationFieldMessage {  
  @Id id,  

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  ValidationField validationField

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "validation_message_id")
  ValidationMessage validationMessage;
}

ValidationMessage {  
  @Id id,  
  text
}
```

The Spring Data repository method is defined as follows:

```
List<ValidationField> findByName(String name);
```

Data example:

> *Validation_Field*
>       **id**  |  **name**
>       0      first_name
>
> *Validation_Field_Message*
>        **id** | **validation_message_id** | **validation_field_id**
>          0        0                              0
>          1        1                              0
>          2        2                              0
>
> *Validation_Message*
>        **id** | **text**
>          0        "There should be no spaces"
>          1        "No special characters are allowed"

The result from the execution however yields the following:

> field {
>     id:0,
>     name:first_name,
>     messages: {
>       [
>          id:0,
>          validationMessage: [
>             id:1,
>             text: "No special characters are allowed"
>          ], [
>             id:1,
>             text: "No special characters are allowed"
>          ]
>       ]
>     }
>   }

The messages are duplicated instead of individually listed.
I've tried with @Query using joins as well, but without success.

Is there something I'm missing in the model definition?

Comment: Are you missing the @JoinColum for ValidationField?

Comment: Not sure this causes your problem, but `mappedBy = "validationMessage"` should be `mappedBy = "validationField"`

Comment: Jens, you have an excellent eye for detail, thanks! That was indeed the problem.